# I want to write a for-loop in python that represents continents moving 2 centimeters over a period of 25 years

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to write a for-loop that displays this information:

```
In year 1, the continents will have moved a total of 2 cm
In year 2, the continents will have moved a total of 4 cm
In year 3, the continents will have moved a total of 6 cm
In year 4, the continents will have moved a total of 8 cm
In year 5, the continents will have moved a total of 10 cm
In year 6, the continents will have moved a total of 12 cm
In year 7, the continents will have moved a total of 14 cm
In year 8, the continents will have moved a total of 16 cm
In year 9, the continents will have moved a total of 18 cm
In year 10, the continents will have moved a total of 20 cm
In year 11, the continents will have moved a total of 22 cm
In year 12, the continents will have moved a total of 24 cm
In year 13, the continents will have moved a total of 26 cm
In year 14, the continents will have moved a total of 28 cm
In year 15, the continents will have moved a total of 30 cm
In year 16, the continents will have moved a total of 32 cm
In year 17, the continents will have moved a total of 34 cm
In year 18, the continents will have moved a total of 36 cm
In year 19, the continents will have moved a total of 38 cm
In year 20, the continents will have moved a total of 40 cm
In year 21, the continents will have moved a total of 42 cm
In year 22, the continents will have moved a total of 44 cm
In year 23, the continents will have moved a total of 46 cm
In year 24, the continents will have moved a total of 48 cm
In year 25, the continents will have moved a total of 50 cm
```

The way I would approach this is making two arrays, one for year and one for centimeters, but there has to be a quicker way to do this than to write two arrays with 25 values in each one. I know i'll have to concatenate the "In Year" and "the continents will have moved a total of" strings, but i'm unsure of how I can make an efficient for-loop to display this information. Where should I start?

Comment: Why do you need an array for it? Just start a for loop, index is the year, move of the continent is just double of the year. You don't need to fill an array for it.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you show your efforts as well. Refer SO's standards for writing a post

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array at all, `range` will do and you get the cm by `year*2`.

```
for num in range(1,26):
    print("In year %2.2s, the continents will have moved a total of %2.2s cm" %( num, num*2))
```

```
In year  1, the continents will have moved a total of  2 cm
In year  2, the continents will have moved a total of  4 cm
In year  3, the continents will have moved a total of  6 cm
In year  4, the continents will have moved a total of  8 cm
In year  5, the continents will have moved a total of 10 cm
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1,21):
    print(f"In year {i} , the continents will have moved a total of {i*2} , cm")
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over 2 [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)s using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for year, cm in zip(range(1, 26), range(2, 51, 2)):
    print(f"In year {year}, the continents will have moved a total of {cm} cm")
```

or even just

```
for year in range(1, 26):
    cm = 2 * year
    print(f"In year {year}, the continents will have moved a total of {cm} cm")
```

depending on your python version you need to write the print statement as

```
print("In year {}, the continents will have moved a total of {} cm".format(year, cm))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
years = range(1, 26)

for y in years:
    print(f'In year {y}, the continents will have moved a total of {y*2} cm')
```

This creates a range of the years you want to display (1 through 25) and then iterates over every year (y) in the range. Then you use a formatted string to print the year and the distance.